# Removing elements alike in a list of strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, fuzzing

This is the first time I ask something here, I'm very new to this so I'll do my best. I have a list with phrases, I want to eliminate all the phrases alike, like:

```
array = ["A very long string saying some things", 
         "Another long string saying some things", 
         "extremely large string saying some things", 
         "something different", 
         "this is a test"]
```

I want this result:

```
array2 = ["A very long string saying some things", 
          "something different", 
          "this is a test"]`
```

I have this:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    swich=True
    for j in range(len(array2)):
        if (fuzz.ratio(array[i],array2[j]) >= 80) and (swich == True):
            swich=False
            pass
        if (fuzz.ratio(array[i],array2[j]) >= 80) and (swich == False):
            array2.pop(j)
```

But it gives me list `IndexError`...

`fuzzy.ratio` compares two strings and gives a value between 0 and 100, the greater, the more alike the strings are.

What I'm trying to do is compare lists element by element, the first time it finds two similar strings, just turn the switch on and pass, from that point every similar finding, pop the element of `array2`. I'm completely open to any suggestions.

Comment: Give the exact error trace...which list has an index error?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is caused by modification of the list, over which you are iterating at that point. (Never add/remove/replace elements of iterables which you currently iterate!) `range(len(array2))` knows that the length was N, but after you `array2.pop(j)`, the length is not N anymore, but N-1. When trying to access N-th element afterwards, you get an `IndexError` because the list is now shorter.

A quick guess on another approach:

```
original = ["A very long string saying some things", "Another long string saying some things", "extremely large string saying some things", "something different", "this is a test"]

filtered = list()

for original_string in original:
    include = True
    for filtered_string in filtered:
        if fuzz.ratio(original_string, filtered_string) >= 80:
            include = False
            break
    if include:
        filtered.append(original_string)
```

Please note `for string in array` loop, which is more "pythonic" and needs no integer variables nor ranges.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a different library which will compact your code and reduce the number of loops?

```
import difflib

def remove_similar_words(word_list):
    for elem in word_list:
        first_pass = difflib.get_close_matches(elem, word_list)
        if len(first_pass) > 1:
            word_list.remove(first_pass[-1])
            remove_similar_words(word_list)
    return word_list


l = ["A very long string saying some things", "Another long string saying some things", "extremely large string saying some things", "something different", "this is a test"]

remove_similar_words(l)

['A very long string saying some things',
 'something different',
 'this is a test']
```